# How to manage custom error message with php

Tags: php, onchange

How can I put a custom error message with php? The x-moz-errormessage works great but not so the oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity.

```
// Formular erstellen
$Formular = $javascript . '
<br><p class="button_center"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="feedback_en.php">to the feedbacks</a></p>

<form name="Form" action="feedback_en.php?eintragen" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<p><br>
<label class="form-control-label">Your name
<input required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please fill this field.');" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){};" x-moz-errormessage="Please fill the field!" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="' . $name . '" size="35" maxlength="35">
</label>
</p>
'
```

Comment: thanks dakis! It worked I had to do it with the onchange="try{setCustomValidity(/'/') as well.
I am super newbie, but I like stack overflow because of guys like you.

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, the other chars I missed :-) Btw, don't write JS code directly in the html attributes. Always use functions instead, no matter how small they are. So, your _try-catch_ block should go into a js function. Then just write the function call as the value of the html attribute. PS: When you address yourself to an SO user, you should use the "@" character in front of the user name. That way the user receives a red badge on the upper right corner of his window, seeing that you commented, or answered to a question. Otherwise he can't see it. Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the surrounding apostrophs in `setCustomValidity('Please fill this field.')`, so that they can be treated by PHP as literal characters, not as closing/opening characters of a PHP string.

Read [Escape sequences](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

So, correct is:

```
$Formular = $javascript . '... oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(\'Please fill this field.\');" ...';
```

---

If, for example, you are writing this simple PHP code in an `test.php` page:

```
<?php

$myName = 'My name is 'Julie'.';

echo $myName;
```

then you'll receive the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Julie' (T_STRING) in
>   [path-to]/test.php on line 3

Whereas the following code with escaped apostrophes will work:

```
<?php

$myName = 'My name is \'Julie\'.';

echo $myName;
```

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much dakis. It works.

Comment: Great to here and glad to have helped.

Comment: @AdrianEdelmann I forgot an advice: try to always avoid building client-side code (html, js, css) from PHP. Just _**fill**_ an already existent client-side code with needed PHP variables. The code in your question is hard to maintain and impossible to format. Code formatting is a very important part regarding productivity and code readability. A good editor makes your dev life very easy with its formatting capabilities. Personally I use NetBeans [v. 8.2](https://netbeans.org/). The new, long awaited [v. 9.0 (stable)](https://netbeans.apache.org) (a different website!) should appear very soon.